# How to use different keys for selecting text in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings, textselection

So I created a separate minor-mode for moving the cursor efficiently, selecting text et cetera (very similar to [Chris Done's god-mode](http://chrisdone.com/posts/god-mode)). But somehow I can't get Emacs to select text when shift-pressing those alternative arrow keys. When I try, the cursor moves but nothing gets selected. Here are my bindings:

```lisp
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "i") 'previous-line)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "j") 'left-char)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "l") 'right-char)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "k") 'next-line)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "I") 'previous-line)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "J") 'left-char)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "L") 'right-char)
(define-key movecursor-keymap (kbd "K") 'next-line)
```

Of course I enabled:

```lisp
(setq shift-select-mode t)
; and also
(transient-mark-mode 1)
```

What do I need to do to enable shift-selection with those keys?

Comment: just a thought, without having tried this locally, but `S-i` will convert to `I` and would call `previous-line`, so is your problem just caused by the uppercased keybindings?

Comment: I tried it without those uppercase keybindings at first but pressing `I` just inserts an `I` then. :(

Answer (score 2):

***Show your code.***  Describe what you expected to happen and what happens instead.  (Always.)

A wild guess would be that you are not setting `deactivate-mark` to `nil` at the end of your command (or whatever code is followed by other code that expects the region to be active).

Put `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` after you do whatever you do and before any code that expects the region to still be active.  Remember that the command loop deactivates the mark after each command.

***UPDATE***

OK, so you want to use shift selection.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "i") (lambda (arg) (interactive "^p") (previous-line arg)))
```

***and***

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "I"))
```

etc.  See:

- `(emacs) Shift Selection`
- `(elisp) Using Interactive`

The former tells you that you must unset `I` if you expect shifted `i` to select text.

Comment: _"Describe what you expected to happen and what happens instead."_ Well, erm… I did? See _"When I try, the cursor moves but nothing gets selected."_ Also, regarding other code that might cause the issues here: I could certainly show you the thousands of lines of code I've got in my .emacs.d/ but the above code is actually a minimal example which reproduces my problem (run emacs -q -l .emacs.test, where .emacs.test contains the code).

Comment: (…with `define-key movecursor-mode-map` obviously being replaced with something like `global-set-key`)

Comment: You missed the point.  Just moving the cursor *never* selects text by itself.  You said that you wrote a "*minor mode for moving the cursor efficiently, selecting text et cetera.*"  I was expecting to see some of that code, since the code you show does not do any text selection at all.  (Oh, and `shift-select-mode` is a variable, not a function.  But that was not your problem, since it is `t` by default.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You're right, I just looked at what `C-n` and the arrow keys are bound to (via `C-h k`) and attempted to copy this behavior for my own keys. But, apparently, `C-h k` will not show the arguments that are passed to the commands? Anyway, I will try the code from your updated post as soon as I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it works if I also do `(global-unset-key (kbd "I"))`. Then, however, I'm not able to type `I` as a normal character anymore. Without it, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Neither does it work if I also bind the lambda you suggested to `I`. Is there any way around this? E.g. is there some argument I could pass to `previous-line` that makes `previous-line` always set the mark so I could bind this to `I`? The only (rather different) solution coming to my mind would be to always explicitly reset the global keybindings when switching from one mode to the other.

Comment: You can try using your keymap where I used `global-map`.  But according to the doc, if there is any binding for `I` then the special region-selection-on-shift behavior for Shift + `i` will not take effect.  The doc seems pretty clear that for that to work the shifted key must not have any other (current) key binding. And `S-i` is the same as `I`.  Perhaps someone else has a suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I actually used my own key map. However, if I unset the global key binding I need to set it again to `self-insert-command` as soon as I switch back to normal writing mode (i.e. disable my minor mode).